# Is there an App like "Codea", but for MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, codea

Is there an App like "Codea" ( http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/ ), but for MonoTouch?
I need a way to write and compile my MonoTouch code directly on the iPad.
I thought about writing my own realtime c# MonoTouch compiler for iPad, but I fear that this is a daunting task. But maybe there are some open source resources already out there.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Codea is using lua interpreter to run lua code at runtime. AFAIK there is no C# interpreter available on iOS

Answer (score 3):

In short, no there isn't. MonoTouch was designed explicitly to allow developers who are using Apple's XCode development environment to embed the Monotouch engine into their IOS applications.  As the commenter mentioned, there is no C# interpreter for IOS.

Learn Lua, it's good for you :)